# Android shorten spinner to content width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

I'm using a spinner do users can choose their age, which looks like this:

[image]

The dropdown arrow is currently too far to the right. How do I set it so that the spinner width is only as short as it needs to be for the contents of the spinner items?

The code for the spinner section of the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Age:" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/input_age_spinner"
            android:layout_weight="0.6" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have tried setting the spinner layout width to wrap_content but it didn't accomplish much. And I have tried setting the spinner layout_weight to 0.2, which does make it narrow, but in that case it is no longer left aligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Age:" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/input_age_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(OR)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Age:" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it with a linearlayout?

Comment: @Simon, Edited my answer, but better to use relative layout like first one. as second one is complex layout.

Comment: Place a Space between the text view and the spinner while using a LinearLayout. Give it a weight of 1 and the text and spinner a weight of 0

Comment: Thanks, that made the spinner smaller, but `android:gravity=left` doesn't seem to do anything as the spinner is aligned to the right side of the parent container. i.e. the spinner should be aligned to the left like the other input widgets

Comment: android:gravity=left is for contents of spinner. if u don't give this, text will come in center.

Comment: @Helix 'Space' needs min sdk version as 14. so if it's ok with that min sdk version, we can use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Age:" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/input_age_spinner"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Age:" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/input_age_spinner" />

</LinearLayout>
```